# TensorFlow Object detection API. How can I get precision and recall after I trained the model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have trained Faster_rcnn_Inception model and other models using my own dataset locally.
But I can only get images with bounding boxes.
I want to get precision and recall to compare models.
I see 'compute_precision_recall' in metrics.py but i don't know how to use it.
My dataset has only one class.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to get the best help you should show relevant code that clarifies your problem and shows some effort to solve it on your part.  This help article offers good advice on what to share: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -1):

These are the following things I did to do calculate the Precision and Recall metrics

1. Run the `inference_detections.py` script(usage is mentioned in the file)  in the `object_detection/inference` directory. A detection record file will be generated using this command in the output path specified.
2. After getting this file(let's say the name is `detections.record`), you can use this to obtain the precision, recall and a confusion matrix with the help of the code in this [repo](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm).A detailed guide explaining how the code works can be found [here](https://www.shiftedup.com/2018/10/10/confusion-matrix-in-object-detection-api-with-tensorflow).

I hope this helps you out

Comment: Can you elaborate on how The github repo enables precission and recall after training the model?

Comment: Do you already have the predicted bounding boxes for each image in your test set?

Comment: I am sorry I was vague in answering before. I have updated my answer. Please let me know if you face any issues, I would be happy to help

Comment: How do you generate input_tfrecord_paths and others? how to use this inference script?